# Saving and reopening Visual Studio

Tags: save, runtime-error

so i made a simple prog in visual studio.

When I closed down the project it was 100% working

Now having reopened the project it tells me there are errors and wont run

The error codes are CS0101 and CS0111

The prog looks like this

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:
            Random rd = new Random();
            double num01 = rd.Next(10,20);
            double num02 = rd.Next(1,10);
            double ans;
            Console.WriteLine("~Press Any Key to Generate Numbers~");
            Console.ReadKey();
       
            Console.WriteLine($"What is {num01} divided by {num02}");
            
            ans = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine());
            if (ans == (num01/num02))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Congratulations you are correct!! {num01/num02} \n ~Press Any Key to try again~");
                Console.ReadKey();
                    goto Start;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You are incorrect! The correct answer is {num01/num02} ~Press Any Key to try again~");
                Console.ReadKey();
                goto Start;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Project was duplicated >_<